# How to represent an enumeration in RDF/XML?

Tags: xml, rdf, owl

I have a code like this:

```
enum ElementKind {
    BASIC (0),
    INTERMEDIATE (1),
    COMPLETE (2);
}

class Element {
    private ElementKind elementKind;

    /* ... */
}
```

I'm building a RDF/XML (ontology) representation for this code:

```xml
<owl:Class rdf:about="#ElementKind">
    // how to define?
</owl:Class>

<owl:Class rdf:about="#Element">
</owl:Class>
```

What is the best way to represent that enumeration?

Comment: 1) I hope you're not building the RDF/XML representation manually;  if you need to write RDF by hand, it's much easier to use N3/Turtle.  2) If you're using things like **owl:Class**, then you're probably writing an OWL ontology, in which case an OWL ontology editor (like Protege) is probably much more helpful.

Comment: As to how to do this, it really depends on how you want to do this.  You could define a data property whose range is a enumeration of values (e.g., hasElementKind with range {"Kind1", "Kind2", "Kind3"}.  Alternatively, you could make the enumeration elements be individuals of some OWL class, e.g., ElementKind = { Kind1, Kind2, Kind3 }.  Which makes more sense really depends on what you want to do with it.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, Joshua Taylor. I'm currently using Protégé. Could you rewrite this as steps into Protégé? I'm also trying to avoid using instances.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're trying to avoid individuals?  That seems a bit counterproductive?  After all, you're using an enumeration in the programming language instead of using "raw data" values like integers.  Isn't one of the points of using enumerated values to provide some meaningful abstraction.  If you don't want to use an abstraction, then you probably shouldn't use "ElementType" in your code, right?  If the "ElementType" values actually correspond to integers (0,1,2), then you could just use integer everywhere, couldn't you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want to convey meaning to a human reader you could go for one of the following two RDF(S) options:

#### 1. RDFS Container

Instances of `rdfs:Container` are intended to convey *to a human reader* that its elements form an open collection. Whether you are dealing with an open collection or not depends on whether or not there exists a fourth option. For your case this would conceptually amount to the following triples:

```
〈ex:elementKind, rdf:type, rdfs:Container〉
〈ex:elementKind, rdf:_1,   ex:basic〉
〈ex:elementKind, rdf:_2,   ex:intermediate〉
〈ex:elementKind, rdf:_3,   ex:complete〉
```

If you want to convey a bit more *human meaning* then you can choose one of the three subclasses of RDFS container:

- Instances of `rdf:Alt` are intended to convey *to a human
  reader* that elements in the container are alternatives of each
  other. This would apply in your case if an element cannot (at the
  same moment) be of two kinds.
- Instances of `rdf:Seq` are
  intended to convey *to a human reader* that the order in which the
  elements occur is significant. This may apply to your case if
  `complete` is  intended to 'follow-up' `intermediate` (in some sense
  of the word) and `intermediate` is intended to 'follow-up' `basic`.
- Instances of `rdf:Bag` are intended to convey *to a human
  reader* that the order in which the elements occur is not
  significant.

Notice that if you use one of these three subclasses of `rdfs:Container` you only need to replace the class-denoting term in the above triples.

#### 2. RDF List

Instances of `rdfs:List` are intended to convey *to a human reader* that the collection of 'element kinds' is closed. For instance, this would imply that there is no fourth 'element kind' that may be added by someone else later. For your case this would conceptually amount to the following triples:

```
〈ex:elementKind, ∊, rdf:List〉
〈ex:elementKind, rdf:first, ex:basic〉
〈ex:elementKind, rdf:rest, _:4〉
〈_:4, ∊, rdf:List〉
〈_:4, rdf:first, ex:intermediate〉
〈_:4, rdf:rest, _:5〉
〈_:5, ∊, rdf:List〉
〈_:5, rdf:first, ex:complete〉
〈_:5, rdf:rest, rdf:nil〉
```

Answer (score 2):

I could think of two ways of representing enumerations: the `DisjointUnion` approach and `OneOf` approach.

1) In the DisjointUnion approach you represent all enumeration constants as classes `E1, ..., En` and define your enumeration to be a disjoint union of those classes:

`DisjointUnion(Enum,E1,...,En)`

This axiom states that all `E1...En` are disjoint and `Enum` is a union of them all (so every instance of `Enum` would be an instance of one `Ei`).

2) You may have all `Ei` being different individuals and define `Enum` as a union of those:

`EquivalentClasses(Enum,OneOf(E1,...,En));
 AllDifferent(E1,...,En)`

Both those methods does not allow you to use C-style bit-field enums that can be ORed together like `std::failbit|std::badbit`